# send email without opening default mail app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to send mail directly from my app to an email address without opening the default mail app on my device. Can this be done, even if it can be is it a good idea ? Does Apple allow doing this ? I have seen this in Amazon’s App where the mail is sent directly from the app. My client wants me to do the same. Please suggest me how this can be done.
Thank you.

Comment: It can't be done from the Mail app. You will have to setup your own SMTP server on the backend, and then use an API to tell the server to send the email.

Comment: Take a look at MailGun. Depending on your volume it may be free

Comment: Thanks, the client was arguing about having to click the send button twice.(face palm !!)

Answer (score 1):

Try **MFMailComposerViewController** which is default functionality provided by Apple.

Try the following code :

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    //[mailComposer.navigationBar setBarTintColor:APPTHEME_COLOR];

    //[mailComposer.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [mailComposer.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]}];

    [mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"support@trackidon.com", nil]];

    [mailComposer setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Report from %@",[USERDEFAULTS objectForKey:USERNAME]]];

    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

This will present one View Controller for Sending Email. You can Edit to Addresses, Subject and body of the content.

This won't direct you out of the app. This will happen inside the app itself.

Hope it helps..

Comment: But this does show a window of the default mail app, which is want i don't want, i used this earlier but the client said no..

Comment: We can't send mail without user's knowledge. If you want to have such functionality, then make one Backend API call. Make that API call to send mail from your backend server.